# Yii autocomplete populated from another autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, yii, autocomplete

After crawling here and there I have tried to set up an auto-complete from another auto-complete in Yii.

The first auto-complete works well !
For the second one the code is missing the part of success data I'm really stuck there how to 'link' it to the _renderItem at the end of the code ???.

Any help appreciated !

```
<?php
// First AUTOCOMPLETE
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'model'=> $model,
    'attribute'=>'esarticle',
    'value' =>$this->createUrl('Utility/autocomplete', array('id'=>'cpl_esarticle','model'=>'Entresortie')),
    'source'=>$this->createUrl('Utility/autocomplete', array('id'=>'cpl_esarticle','model'=>'Entresortie')),
    'options'=>array(
        'focus'=> 'js:function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#Entresortie_esarticle" ).val( ui.item.esarticle );
            return false;
            }',
        'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#Entresortie_esarticle" ).val( ui.item.esarticle );
            return false;
            }'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'size'=>12,
            'maxlength'=>14,
            'autofocus'=>'autofocus',
         ),));

// Second AUTOCOMPLETE
$quotedUrl = $this->createUrl('entresortie/cpl_eslot');
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
    'model'=> $model,
    'attribute'=>'eslot',
    'value' =>$this->createUrl('Utility/autocomplete', array('id'=>'cpl_eslot','model'=>'Entresortie')),
    'source'=>'js:function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "'. $quotedUrl . '",
            data: { "term": request.term, "art":$( "#Entresortie_esarticle" ).val() },
            success: function(data) { response(data); }
            });
    }',
    'options'=>array(
           'focus'=> 'js:function( event, ui ) {
               $( "#Entresortie_eslot" ).val( ui.item.eslot );
               return false;
            }',
            'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#Entresortie_eslot" ).val( ui.item.eslot );
                return false;
            }'),
     'htmlOptions'=>array(
         'size'=>12,
         'maxlength'=>14,
         'autofocus'=>'autofocus',
      ),));

// Additional script to fill the autocomplete list
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('input', '
    $("#Entresortie_esarticle").data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>"+item.esarticle+"</a>")
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
     $("#Entresortie_eslot").data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>"+item.eslot+"</a>")
            .appendTo( ul );
        };');
 ?>
```

Comment: To be noted : on the second autocomplete in the sucess function the data field is well populated by the JSON string returned by my query. But then I need to 'fill' my autocomplete field with these values...

Comment: I solve my problem by doing a two step forms. However I'm still would quite interested if someone found one answer !